# Sorting OData model in SAPUI5

Tags: odata, sapui5

Dear SAPUI5 Developers,

I developed a `SAPUI5 Fiori Worklist` project by using `WebIDE` template projects.

In the `Component.js` file the OData model has been fetched.

```
var sServiceUrl = this.getMetadata().getManifestEntry("sap.app").dataSources.mainService.uri;
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, {
            json: true,
            loadMetadataAsync: true
        });
        oModel.attachMetadataFailed(function() {
            // Call some functions from APP controller to show suitable message
        }, this);
        this.setModel(oModel, "BrandSet");
```

This part of code causes a call to OData server to fetch data from the remote server.
Now I want to order the data in backend and then receive the data. Assume the sorting function has been implemented correctly in the backend. 
Thus, if I use `$orderby=name` or `$orderby=price` it has to be sorted by name or price respectively.

In some toturial they said for ordering use `sorter` option inside of the XML view file. Like here:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/c4b2a32bb72f483faa173e890e48d812.html

Now my questions are:

1. How to apply this sorting inside of the `Component.js` file where the Model is initiated?
2. The second question is how to apply this ordering when we apply a filter to the model? Like the example that in the following link applied filter:
   https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/5295470d7eee46c1898ee46c1b9ad763.html

In fact I am looking for a function or any kind of method that add the `$orderby=xxx` to the OData service call.

I found a way here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#constructor

If I use `mParameters.serviceUrlParams` then I can add some URL parameter to the service request but it has been said *"these parameters will be attached **to all** requests"*. Does it mean if I add the `$orderby`with this method then I can not get rid of that in the further requests on that data model for example for filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An app would normally be structured a bit differently to what you propose.  The general assumption is that there is a lot of data available from the backend and to load all this data at once can cause performance problems, particularly when used over a mobile phone network.  Furthermore, the data is an oData Entity Set, that is, a list of many items of the same type, so the data would be presented in the UI with a list or table.

Typically the app would then show the data in some kind of list, such as sap.m.List or sap.m.Table. These controls are designed to work with large volumes of data and would load initially the first 20 items from the entity set.  Only when the user scrolls down the list of data would additional items be loaded.  Also, with these controls the user can decide to sort or filter the data according to certain fields in your data.

Assuming that your app is work like this, here is the standard approach.

The Main model (as defined in the manifest) would not be loaded in Component.js, but loaded via the binding defined in the xml views of the app.  In the views you could define a fixed sort and/or filter in the binding or you could allow the user to set the sort and filter criteria.  This would be handled programmatically in the respective controllers.  Normally the changes that the user makes to the sort and filter would be applied separately.  For example, he/she chooses an new sort order, the oData is reread and the new sort order shown in the UI.  Then the user may chose a filter criteria, and this is applied too.  Of course, in your programming logic in the controllers you would need to have applied any default sort and filter criteria and then maybe combine or replace these with the criteria selected by the user.

To see an example of this, I would suggest to look at the Template Application “SAP Fiori Master-Detail Application” in the WebIDE.

Comment: Thanks. A perfect answer. It made many things clear for me. But I have this question yet... Is it possible to set an initial order for a OData model programmatically or not? (I mean in JavaScript and not in XML view)

Comment: Also please note that I used the Worklist template of the WebIDE and loading the data inside of the Component.js has been made by WebIDE.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to set an initial sort order pragmatically. Please see [Aggregation Binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f057786f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)

Comment: Regarding your second comment, I took a look at the Worklist Template.  There, the data for the worklist is loaded via the XML View (Table binding).  In the component.js, there is a model for “device” (provides access to information regarding the device) and “FLP” model (provides access to information regarding the user from Launchpad).

Comment: You are right. It was better I mentioned that I am using SAPUI5 Version 1.28. What you said is correct on V1.38 and later.

Comment: Caution: 
Automatic model instantiation is only available as of SAPUI5 version 1.30. If you are using an older version, you can manually instantiate the resource bundle and other models of the app in the init method of the Component.js file as we did in Step 9: Component Configuration.. Ref: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/8f93bf2b2b13402e9f035128ce8b495f.html